# Custom Form Field in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I am trying to create a custom form field in Django.

```
class CustomTypedMultipleChoiceField(MultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.coerce = kwargs.pop('coerce', lambda val: val)
        self.empty_value = kwargs.pop('empty_value', [])
        super(CustomTypedMultipleChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        """
        Validates that the values are in self.choices and can be coerced to the
        right type.
        """
        value = super(CustomTypedMultipleChoiceField, self).to_python(value)
        if value == self.empty_value or value in self.empty_values:
            return self.empty_value
        new_value = []
        for choice in value:
            try:
                new_value.append(self.coerce(choice))
            except (ValueError, TypeError, ValidationError):
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % {'value': choice})
        return new_value

    def validate(self, value):
        if value != self.empty_value:
            super(CustomTypedMultipleChoiceField, self).validate(value)
        elif self.required:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
```

I am getting the error `CustomTypedMultipleChoiceField` has no attribute `empty_values`. This is the exact same code that Django in built `TypedMultipleChoiceField` is built with. So I dont understand why I am getting this error. 
I also thought of sub-classing the `TypedMultipleChoiceField`, but I wanted its error to be different in `to_python` method and didn't want to return the value thing, so opted for this method.
Please help me.

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: Django 1.5.1 is the version I m using. What has that got to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a typo or you intended that way but actually `empty_values` (in plural) is not defined in your code anywhere. I also take a look at the source code of the super class `MultipleChoiceField` and is not defined there either.

What I could find in the super super class of your class (`ChoiceField`) was a reference to `validator.EMPTY_VALUES` and of course, it is in capital letters.

The line more alike yours in the source code was this one:

```
if value == self.empty_value or value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
```

Take a look deep in your code and see if that was what you intended to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't intend to change that as I have mentioned in the question. Just wanted to change the error part. I have seen the codes and in it they also have created typed multiple choice field in the same manner. They don't get an error so why am I getting one?

Comment: Seems your code is right. I suggest you do some debugging with pdb to see what's actually happening.